How to fetch hash values for multiple keys in redis ? Is there a mhgetall operation?
HSET myhash field2 "Hi" field3 "World"
HSET myhash2 field2 "Hi" field3 "World"

I want to fetch the key-values for mhash and myhash2 in one operation. how to do this ?

There is no native way that redis supports fetching keys of two hash-maps in one operation

do u know why ? can this be added ?

I am not sure of the reason, but you can always implement your custom method/functions where you can take in 2 or more keys, internally look them up 1 by 1 and then return them once all keys are fetched

you can use this command. hgetall "key"

you also can use hscan "key"

you also can use hmget "key1" "key2"  .... "keyn"

You want to get/modify the two keys in a single query to save some network transports? Do this in batch. If you want it, then you have to take the power of pipeline:
https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/use/pipelining/
(printf 'HSET myhash field2 "Hi" field3 "World"\r\nHSET myhash2 field2 "Hi" field3 "World"\r\n'; sleep 1) | nc localhost 6379

